# Can one get the private key from a transaction?

Tags: blockchain

maybe someone can get the private key from the blockchain tx?

(gal kas galetu isskaiciuoti privatu rakta is blockchain tranksacijos)

ca44c58e53ba0f5a66903dd573e8b21b966e156dcfccd1da676565a2a8d1ad22 "value": "0.32538400",
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "hex": "76a9143c61ec465407c4de44b46138afcbd3845e96134788ac",
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 3c61ec465407c4de44b46138afcbd3845e961347 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "addresses": [
          "16WGrKJUZ3LrRms88kkmQyTLzVs8dyJD8a"
        ],
        "type": "pubkeyhash"
      },
      "spentTxId": null,
      "spentIndex": null,
      "spentHeight": null

Comment: Hi Nijiole, this is an english speaking forum. I translated your question accordingly. When you have a publicly recorded data (from the blockchain), the whole point is that you are not able to get the private key, otherwise the security model of the bitcoin would be broken. Also your question is very short, maybe you want to extend it, to get better answers (see here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are irreversible hashing algorithms involved so that there is no way to get the private key from a transaction.

Otherwise, everyone could send foreign bitcoins away.

Answer (score 0):

Can one get facebook account password from looking at that person's facebook posts?

Obviously No. It defies all the meanings of passwords/private keys stand for.